# Getting projected Image pixel locations

Tags: c++, image, opencv, camera, projector

I'm working on a thesis that'll need a module that can get the pixel area of a projected image(image that a projector projects). I've got an idea but i don't think it is feasible and accurate as I don't have any experience in computer vision, let me explain the idea.

To get the pixel area or location of let's say, a certain file in a projected image.

1. Capture the projected image by a camera.
2. Convert the captured image's resolution to the projector's.
3. get the file location/pixel area in the captured image.

I haven't tried the idea yet as I don't have a projector right now. Oh and, I'm developing my system in C++. The thesis basically is an interactive projected image by providing touchscreen like functions.

**To make it clear, What I'm trying to do is project the computer's screen in a projector and then capture/record it with a camera and get the projected image pixel locations. the problem is how can I get the image pixel location in a projected image with the fact that it is in the real world and it's properties will be transformed such as it's size and dimensions?**

If you think the idea is not feasible, please spare some time to comment why and if possible could you please give me an idea on how to handle the problem. I am open for any suggestions.

I'll be glad to answer any questions.

Comment: similar to [reactable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactable) ?

Comment: it's much like of a hand gesture recognition system ,I just innovated it with touch-screen like functions. That's how I got this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you know the projected image size, which I assume is true by (2.) in your question, then you can simply use normalized co-ordinates x' = (x / width), y' = (y / height).  Then you can convert a location between any sized images by recovering x = (x'*width), y = (y'height). There will be some rounding errors, but that can't be avoided.

Cheers

edit: also assuming the centers are decently aligned.

Comment: so you basically think my idea from 1 to 2 might work and those that you have said will be applied on the 3rd step ? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Well if their centers are perfectly aligned then there is no problem with with using the normalized coordinates, however in a real system you would prob. need to find the homography (mapping) between them.  i.e. like this http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography,  or have a nicely calibrated setup such that you know the mapping in advance.

Comment: I have read something about mapping but I haven't read thoroughly, Thanks for pointing on it now I have a direction to move, appreciated it.